# styleClass does not work in pageTreeNode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-domino

In bootstrap for xPages pageTreeNode (Application layout, responsive application layout) the styleClass does not seems to have any effect. 
Here for example, I'd expect the menu item "Link 1" to have the class testClass associated with it.

```
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
    <xe:this.facets>
        <xp:callback facetName="facetRight" id="facetRight"
            xp:key="RightColumn">
        </xp:callback>
    </xe:this.facets>
    <xp:callback facetName="facetMiddle" id="facetMiddle"></xp:callback>
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
            <xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                <xe:basicLeafNode label="Link 1"
                    styleClass="testClass" href="http://www.bbc.com/">
                </xe:basicLeafNode>
            </xe:this.titleBarTabs></xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
    </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout></xp:view>
```

And the generated code is

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 applayout-titlebar-tabsarea"><ul id="view:_id1:_id2:applicationLayout1_tb" class="nav nav-tabs applayout-titlebar-tabs">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="http://www.bbc.com/">Link 1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Am I missing something vital?

Comment: BTW I have added a style sheet that has the class in it.

Comment: As a workaround, try using the "attrs" in all properties.  Push the plus and create a new one, give it the name "class" and your value.  See if this works.

Comment: I don't think what I told you is possible in my first comment, for the nodes there is no "attrs" like in most XPages controls.  You could also append a style class on page load using jQuery.

Comment: Adding style 
<xe:basicLeafNode label="Link 1" styleClass="testClass" href="http://www.bbc.com/" style="color:red"></xe:basicLeafNode> works, but not styleClass

Comment: Guessing here...but it looks like this is inherited from oneUI, which can behave annoying like you are finding out.  Your choices 1) Force a style using jQuery on the page load 2) Apply CSS based on generated classes (iffy) 3) Use inline styles like you found to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a bug, I reported this to IBM back in Dec 2014

https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/issues/8

Sadly IBM do not answer bug requests until they are fixed

Comment: As Thomas says, we are aware of the issue. The more reports of it that we get, the higher weight it will get, and make it more likely a fix is pushed through. However, at the moment, this issue does not have a high priority. Customers are free to submit pull requests with suggested fixes on github though, which may make it appear in an extlib release sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see Thomas's answer when I made my comment. If this is the case, then your options are:

1. Force a style using jQuery on the page load, then use your custom css.
2. Apply CSS based on *generated* classes to isolate the item you want to style  (iffy)
3. Use inline styles like you found to work using the "style" property